# Using a struct as a proxy for a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a set up a bit like this...

`protocol A {}`

`protocol B {}`

`protocol C: A, B {}`

So I can create a struct `Foo` that conforms to `C` and use `Foo` anywhere that accepts either an `A` or a `B`.

But if I now want a struct `Bar` that just conforms to `A` (but in a similar way to `Foo`'s conformity to `A`) I need to duplicate all the code from `Foo` into `Bar`.

Is there a way that I can tell `Foo` something like... "Here's another struct that conforms to `A`, I want you to use that to fulfill your conformity to `A`."

Does that make sense?

Comment: If I am not wrong you are trying to extend struct in similar way to class

Comment: @SumitOberoi not necessarily to extend it but to say "for each of these protocol methods just use the method from this other struct which is a property of myself.".

Comment: @fogmister sounds very strange, I don't think thats possible, though will like to research on such a scenario.

Comment: @SumitOberoi just trying to do it to avoid having duplicate code. Although, I may just change my approach. LOLL!

Comment: @SumitOberoi hmm... ok, I think I have something. Just trying now.

Comment: @Fogmeister what about default protocol implementation (aka 'protocol extension')? Could it be an option for your case?

Comment: Thanks both, managed to find a way to get it working with a default implementation of `C` that calls to `A` and `B` to get the property of it. So it sort of works. I'll keep going and see where it ends up.